# AS3 gotoAndStop not working correctly.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently trying to make a login system in Flash.

I tried downloading this source:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1/

My only problem at this moment is that I want to make it change to next frame if the value is "1".

So I changed this:

```
result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
```

Into this:

```
if (event.target.data.systemResult == "1") {
                result_text.text = "Welcome!!";
                this.gotoAndStop('2');
            } else {
                result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
            }
```

But then it just says "Welcome!!" but it doesn't go to next frame -.-'

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is your event in that context, because you're in an event handling closure.

Try `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);`

And make sure you lose the '' from around the 2, as @SrRichie already suggested.

From your screenshot, this should also work:

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop('LoggedIn');
```

If `root` is null (and I haven't looked through the tutorial you reference in detail, so I'm not sure), you may need to create a variable earlier in your code to refer to `root`, and then call `gotoAndStop` on that.

Comment: How do I make the variable `root`?

Comment: Somewhere in the correct scope, add something like `var myRoot:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);` Then you can use `myRoot.gotoAndStop(2);` The issue is one of scope. There's a good SO thread regarding this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749650/actionscript-3-0-scope